# Disabling Lock Workstation feature Securely

Tags: windows-xp

In [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/96228/disabling-lock-workstation-in-windows-xp) I figured out how to disable the `Lock` feature in Windows XP throught the registry. Just by creating a DWORD key named `DisableLockWorkstation` with value 1 in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

But in this solution, the current user can also re-enable this feature in the same way (by setting the value of `DisableLockWorkstation` to 0 or even deleting it).

I know there is ACLs for registry and it is possible to restrict the user access and deny write access to this path. But I am searching for a simpler solution.

Is there any other solution to disable lock feature (for example by setting a value in HKLM instead of HKCU hive)?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you think using ACL's for this is not simple, it seems fairly trivial to me. Also it might help clarify your thinking if you would explain why you need to disable the locking feature, is this a shared user environment where users might try to hog the systems by locking them?

Comment: ACL's are simple in by using GUI of windows. But i should disable/enable lockworkstation programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user has "Administrator" rights then there's nothing you can do to prevent them from making any changes they want to the computer.

Assuming you're doing the Right Thing<sup>(tm)</sup> and your user accounts are all limited users, setting this value (hopefully using the Group Policy setting "Remove Lock Computer" from User Configuration / Administrative Templates / System / Ctrl-Alt-Del Options) will do fine.

By default, inheritance is blocked and an ACL placed in the user's registry at "HKCR\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies" to grant the user "Read" access only to that subtree. Microsoft already though of what you're thinking about and prepared for me... >smile<